# Can't update Developer Tools on Mojave

Tags: macos, terminal, software-update, mojave

Hello,

This question is about the Command Line Developer Tools that are usually installed with `xcode-select --install` and updated via a software update from the Mac App Store (at least until macOS 10.13). I use the developer toolchain on a daily basis and it has always worked and updated without issues.

Today I've updated my mac from High Sierra 10.13.6 to Mojave 10.14.1, and I've lost the ability to update the Developer Tools.

After the update I've executed a terminal command that relies on the developer tools being installed. It was a command to update [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), although I don't think that the specifics matter, as I believe that any task that tried to access the developer tools would have triggered the same error message.

The error was:

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

[image]

The phrasing was new (maybe), but I thought that it was caused by the usual need to re-install the Developer Tools after some macOS updates.

Later I tried to dig a bit deeper into the failure, and found out that:

```
$ ls -l /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  admin  96  4 Nov 19:32 share

$ which xcrun
/usr/bin/xcrun

$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Still, as I normally do, I entered the command to install and update the Developer Tools in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

This started the usual procedure: modal window to confirm, then request to accept the license agreement, followed by a progress bar. Except that it failed very quickly with an unexpected error:

> Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.

[image]

I've tried several times, to no avail. It gets always stuck.

Sometimes, however, the failure causes the System Preferences to report a pending update:

[image][image]

If I open that preference panel it starts searching for updates, and it always finds nothing except the first time that it happened. The first time, it found this:

[image]

[image]

It literally suggested me to install the updates for macOS 10.11 and 10.13. I have no idea why.

I closed the preference without installing, and as I said it hasn't shown them again. There is also no update available in new Mac App Store.

Is this a known issue? Is there any way to resolve the problem?

---

#### Update

Of course I can download the Dev Tools for macOS 10.14 installer from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.

Before installing them manually, though, I'm wondering if there is anything that's broken with the system.

Comment: Hi, how old is your Mac, and was the El Capitan ever on it.

Comment: It's definitely not a new system. It has run all versions of macOS since Mountain Lion. I've been wondering about doing a clean install, but I'd reserve it as a last resort.

Comment: Just wondering why would it offer you to install El Capitan stuff. ? did your OS loose its identity ? or is your profile at Apple Developer corrupt.

Comment: I've been wondering the same. Both El Capitan and High Sierra. I can't think of a reason other than a bug. The previous versions of the dev tools are not installed, and I don't think that there are any stray metadata files left behind, otherwise the El Capital tools would have interfered with the dev tool update process on both Sierra and High Sierra, which has always run smoothly.

Comment: To be honest, it seems odd enough an issue that I am not expecting a good explanation of why it's happening. I'm just hoping someone else has encountered the same issue and has some resolution steps, although a web search didn't return anything relevant.

Comment: `xcrun` tells you the problem: your command line tools path: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` is wrong. It's not your fault, Apple just decided to move it. Simply fix it with `xcode-select`.

Comment: Hi @danielAzuelos, that's what I did and, as described in the question, didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the original poster. In the end I resolved the problem by installing the tools manually, with the installer I downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem. The way I have solve the issue is given below.

1. I got the new xcode 10.1 from App Store. Though the problem existed.
2. Then I run `xcode-select --install` which didn’t work.
3. I update my homebrew by `brew update`. Than I run `sudo xcode-select --reset`.

Now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It started to work without doing nothing special.
I only run the following commands:

`xcode-select -print-path`

then

`cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man`

finally

`whatis xcode-select`

after that I was able again to run commands like `git` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I did this already and it didn't help. `xcode-select --print-path` is the same as `xcode-select -p`, for which I've provided the output in my question. It's interesting that on your system it resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW here's what helped me:

1. Uninstall Homebrew completely (see [FAQ](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew)).
2. `sudo xcode-select --reset` (thanks for the idea @Boka!).
3. Install Homebrew again (see [brew.sh](https://brew.sh)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't help in my case. The problem is not with homebrew, it's with `xcode-select`. The homebrew installation is simply a user of the tools installed by `xcode-select`. If the problem wasn't raised by running a homebrew command, it would be raised by any other direct call or shell script that tried to use one of those tools (e.g. `clang`, `make`). I know because I tried. As I told @Boka, also, `xcode-select --reset` didn't help in my case.

Comment: Sure, my problem was also with Command Line Tools rather than Homebrew, with similar symptoms (failing on being “not currently available” and offering strange updates in Preferences) so I left the comment just In case. Sad to hear that didn’t help you — perhaps some other variables are different (presence of Xcode itself? current state of Homebrew installation? etc)

Comment: There is no Xcode installed, and the state of Homebrew should not be relevant.